# Initialize CoreData Date with nil

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to create a new row in core data with Date values as nil:

```
@ObservedObject var mealsController = CoreDataController()

...

Button(action: {
    self.mealsController.createEntry(meal_type: "Test", status: "notSet", will_eat: nil, eaten: nil)
}) {
    Image(systemName: "text.badge.plus")
}
```

but when I try to do so, I get the error: `'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type 'Date'`

How can I define there that value as nil? I need to pass it to my controller as nil because I'm reading it in a text so until it is set I don't want it to have a value.

UPDATE:
This is the create entry that it refers to on another class, it's basically the same thing:

```
// Create
    func createEntry(meal_type: String, status: String, will_eat: Date, eaten: Date) {
        _ = Meals(id: UUID(), meal_type: meal_type, status: status, eaten: eaten, will_eat: will_eat)
        saveToPersistentStore()
    }
```

and then I'm saving it to Core Data like:

```
func saveToPersistentStore() {
        let moc = CoreDataStack.shared.mainContext
        do {
            try moc.save()
            getMeals()

        } catch {
            NSLog("Error saving managed object context: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the code for `createEntry`.

Comment: @Frankenstein I update the code to be more explicit, does that help? I think it's mainly a problem of initializing core data objects right?

Comment: Why do you need to save it directly, skip that and the error will go away. Then handle eventual validation errors in your controller class. Or wait with creating your object until you have all the data.

Comment: Yep that could be a way, I was just trying to reuse the same function instead of creating a new one. Still the doubt remains... how to set it to nil lol @Frankenstein

Comment: @Spyky Ok could you also post the model. Also check if the answer helps.

Comment: Where do you get the error message excatly?

Comment: @davidev when assigning the value nil to the Entity of core data since it cannot be nil

Comment: This line?   _ = Meals(id: UUID(), meal_type: meal_type, status: status, eaten: eaten, will_eat: will_eat) You are creating the object without a context to the CoreData context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your objects with the CoreData context.

```
//assign the context to the object
let meal = Meals(context: self.moc)

meal.id = UUID()
.... 
meal.will_eat = nil // or just remove that line 

saveToPersistentStore()
```

I am referencing to your moc declared in the other function..

```
let moc = CoreDataStack.shared.mainContext
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your createEntry code, but set your dates as optional in CoreData or your createEntry function by using "?" while declaring them:

```
class YourCoreDataEntity: NSManagedObject,Identifiable {
    @NSManaged var name:String
    @NSManaged var status:String
    @NSManaged var date1:Date?
    @NSManaged var date2:Date?
}
```

Comment: This actually should make it work. I use many Date declared as optional which works fine. Just to add, you have to set the Codegen to Manual/None for your entity

Comment: @davidev nop, if I grab that value, it will complain that I need to unwrap it or provide a default which we are on the same spot

Comment: @Spyky But optional is checked of the attribute?

Comment: @davidev it seems so, look how I have it an gives me error: `@NSManaged var date1:Date?
        _ = Meals(id: UUID(), meal_type: meal_type, status: status, eaten: date1, will_eat: date1)`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: In case you actually require that the `dates` cannot be empty and must contain a value you can use default values like `.distantFuture` or `.distantPast`. This would provide for more flexibility to change the values later on. Here is the code:

```
self.mealsController.createEntry(meal_type: "Test", status: "notSet", will_eat: .distantFuture, eaten: .distantPast)
```

You need to update your `createEntry` function such that it accepts optional `Date?` parameters for `will_eat` and `eaten` as follows:

```
func createEntry(meal_type: String, status: String, will_eat: Date?, eaten: Date?) {
    _ = Meals(id: UUID(), meal_type: meal_type, status: status, eaten: eaten, will_eat: will_eat)
    saveToPersistentStore()
}
```

Note: You might also have to make minor changes to your model according to your requirement.

Alternate Approach: You could set both the date as `Date()` and at the place of displaying check if both the dates are `equal` instead of checking they are `nil`. Here is some code:

```swift
Button(action: {
    let now = Date()
    self.mealsController.createEntry(meal_type: "Test", status: "notSet", will_eat: now, eaten: now)
}) {
    Image(systemName: "text.badge.plus")
}

// And at the place of displaying

Text(meal.will_eat == meal.eaten ? "Date is not set." : "Date is set.")
```

Comment: That will complain about `Value of optional type 'Date?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Date'` and unwrapping it

Comment: The problem is that core data doesn't seem to accept nil values on Dates

Comment: I mean... that works but it's not what I want which is nil. The thing is that I'm showing this date in the UI, if it's nil it won't appear, if it contains a date it does. That's why I need it nil

Comment: I've given you a work-around. Since your model doesn't accept optional this can only be resolved by a work-around. You might want to make modifications in checking if the date has been set or not. Maybe add a boolean to your model `isDateSet`.

Comment: @Spyky Ok so I've added an alternate approach code to my answer.